# Nautilus doesn't display contents of newly chosen directory

Tags: nautilus, 17.10

It happens sporadically and I've yet to notice anything else that's consistently correlated to this issue (which, I realize, makes it difficult to replicate and/or diagnose), but often times during the past month or so, when selecting a new directory from the sidebar of an already open nautilus window, the contents of the previous directory remain displayed.  Clicking again on the desired directory, or trying to choose another directory from the sidebar, fail to do anything to the list of contents nautilus was already displaying.

I can, as a work around, right click on the directory and open it (successfully) in a new tab.

It's worth noting that the window isn't 'frozen'--the newly selected directory becomes highlighted in the sidebar, and other features of the window are entirely functional, but the directory listing remains unchanged.